# Is buying a mortgaged property profitable?

Tags: mortgage, india, loans, rental-property

I am planning to buy a property and wondering if this property is worth buying.

A. Price of property including everything: Rs 45 lacks

B. Down payment: Rs 5 lacks

C. Loan/Mortgage (C = A-B): Rs 40 lack

D. Let's say the property appreciates at 10% a year. Appreciation = Rs 450000

E. Property sold at considering 10% appreciation: Rs 4950000 lacks (A+D)

F. Rental income earned for 1 year = 144000

G. Gain by holding property = D+E = 594000

F. Interest paid to bank on 40 lacks @6.8%  = Rs 272000

H. Interest lost on down payment on 5 lacks for 1 year at 6.8%= 34000

I. Total interest paid for holding property = 306000

J. Net gain = G-I = 288000

K. ROI = Net Gain/Downpayment * 100 =  288000/500000 = 57%

Am i missing somethin/Are my calculations are correct?

As long as the property appreciates at 6.68% am not loosing money. Correct? The way I calculated this is as follows.

```
Total interest paid for holding property/ Total Price paid to buy = I/A*100 = 6.68
```

Comment: What if the price of the property does not increase 10% per year?

Comment: @Flux Thats an assumption. We cannot be sure.

Comment: 10% appreciation per year is pretty optimistic. The time frame for real estate investment is typically decades not years. You will hardly get 10% annualized over the long run even in markets that are considered crazy. Even your 6.68% annualized appreciation is already rather high

Comment: Also do not forget the things that can go wrong. Your tenant might not pay rent, might damage the property, etc. There are a lot of risks with rental properties that tend to even out for a large property owner with hundreds of units but are impossible to properly quantify for a single property (as they can be everywheren from 0 to a high number)

Comment: You left out inflation, which is currently running at about 5% in India, and will eat into your returns.

Comment: What would you invest your money in, if you don't buy this property? You should consider what else you would be earning in the meantime, called in finance the 'opportunity cost'. When doing so, consider that real estate can be riskier than many other options, so that should impact how you compare it to something like an interest rate at a bank.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak to details in India, but if I were doing this analysis in the US here are some things that I would see as missing:

- Property insurance
- Taxes
- Maintenance costs
- You are not taking into account how often the property will go unrented.

Plus, you are assuming a constant appreciation rate of 10%, which seems very optimistic. You should run the analysis at varying appreciation and occupancy rates and see if there are some scenarios which you make less than you could with other, safer investments.

I'm not saying you *shouldn't* do it, but having a mortgage on an investment increases the chances of losing the investment (i.e. if you can't make the mortgage payment because it goes unrented) and sucks away a portion of the profit to interest. So the profit can increase (because of leverage) but the risk increase as well.

Comment: I've made the claim that longterm the price of a house will follow wage inflation. Any higher, and the % of income going to housing will rise. Ok, a long term shift from say 25 to 33%. But it flattens out as some level. Interest rates rise and fall, and lower rates allow that same monthly payment to buy more house. If a property doesn't run at a profit in year one, it's not worth buying. Counting on increases that make never come is a bad way to invest in real estate.